# How to check if current index is last index in array?

Tags: c, arrays

How do I say?

```
for (i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
{
    if (someArray[i + 1] !NULL)
    {
        //do this
    }
    else
    {
        //do something else
    }
}
```

In other words, I want to check if the current index is the last index in the array. The current code is my best guess but it isn't working.

EDIT: It is an integer array and i less than arraySize not 0

EDIT 2: The code inside my for loop is more complicated than the example above but I can't paste all the code as it is top secret atm. I have many nested if statements. `if(i==arraySize-1)` helped me to solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: don't understand your question! but `arraySize -1` should be your last index

Comment: What is this: "*`if (someArray[i + 1] !NULL)`*"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following line will give you count of items in your array:

```
count  = sizeof (intMyArray)/sizeof(intMyArray[0]);
```

if you know arraySize then:

```
if(i==arraySize-1){
  //last element of array
}
```

Comment: Divide by `sizeof(someArray[0])` would be better since that will work even if the type changes (without having to update this code).

Comment: @Kninnug good point!!! but only problem is you dont know whether someArray[0] is null or not.

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed: No issue, you could even do `sizeof((int *) NULL)[0])` as (somehow sickly obsfucated) equivalent to `sizeof(int)`. The expression is evaluated at compile-time.

Comment: @alk: To be precise, the operand of `sizeof` is not evaluated at all (per C 2011 [N1570] 6.5.3.4 2) unless it is a variable-length array. The compiler determines the size from the type of the operand.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Yes, using *"evaluated*" was indeed the wrong wording ... - thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 0):

Size of Array:

```
int array[20], i;
// ...
// fill array
// ...
int sz = sizeof(array)/sizeof(int);
for(i=0; i < sz;i++) {
if(array[i] != 0x0) {
// do something
}
}
```